# Creating work notes

Tags: ruby

I've created a program that will create work notes for me, however, I've been under the impression since I started writing in Ruby that `while` loops are bad. How can I write this differently in order to gain the same effect or an even better effect?

```
def prompt(input)
  print "[#{Time.now.strftime('%T')}] #{input}: "
  STDIN.gets.chomp
end

def work_performed
  count = 0
  notes = ''
  while true
    input = prompt("Enter work notes[#{count += 1}]")
    notes << "\n" + "#{input}\n"
    if input.empty?
      return notes
    else
      while input.empty? != true
        input = prompt('Enter work notes[*]')
        notes << "  - #{input}\n"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way for me to write this without using `while` loops that will be more *Ruby-ish*?

Comment: Titles should only state the code's purpose.  Things such as "better way" aren't needed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to use `loop do ... end` instead of `while true ... end`. See https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#infinite-loop.

I would store notes internally as array, and add newlines only for output. This will allow for further processing if needed, for instance a special input would show last 5 added notes without stopping the loop.

Also I would add a state machine to deal with 'note continuation' vs 'new note' state, instead of nesting loops:

```
current_state = :new
loop do
  messages = {
    new: "Enter work notes[#{count += 1}]",
    current: 'Enter work notes[*]'
  }
  actions = {
    new: -> (input) do ... end,
    current: -> (input) do ... end
  }
  input = prompt(messages[current_state])
  actions[current_state].call(input)
  return if current_state == :end
end
```

in the lambdas, update the state and the storage, and let it go.

Answer (score 2):

Naming is an important part of the code.

```
def prompt(input)
  print "[#{Time.now.strftime('%T')}] #{input}: "
  STDIN.gets.chomp
end
```

Your argument is more than a simple input, it's a message to display in the prompt. You could rename it something `message_to_prompt` or something similar.

I am not a fan of comparing boolean to have a negation. The negation operator exist for a good reason! Use : `while input.empty?` ! What would have been better is either a `not_empty?` or `blank?` method! This express exactly what you want to do!

I know this is a script for your personnal use, but keep in mind that beginning the program with a small how-to is somewhat profitable!

Regarding your while loop, sometimes even if does not feel like the most ruby way there are still good case to use it, and your case is one. Since you're depending on user input to terminate you don't really know when you're going to finish looping.

Comment: I don't really have time to dig in more! This is a small answer, but hey better than nothing. I would have like to tackle the duplication between the title creation and the body since it's just input + write two times, but I didn't find an elegant solution

Comment: No problem for the short answer, I appreciate the input and it's a valid point. Thank you.

Comment: I did not write it in my answer, but I don't feel like there would be another way around your while loop. Sometime that's exactly what you need.

Comment: Yeah, it just looks so `python`ish it bugs me.. Once again though, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome I second Marc-Andre's conclusion: Sometimes a `while` loop is exactly what you need. It's rare in Ruby, since you have a ton of other iterator methods - but typically you're dealing with known-length collections or have ways of breaking out of a loop. With user input, you simply don't know what'll happen, so a `while` loop is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried avoiding nesting the two loops in the top level of your code by hiding one away in a function:

```
def inputs_until_empty(message)
  Enumerator.new do |e|
    while true
      input = prompt(message)
      break if input.empty?
      e.yield input
    end
  end
end
```

This helper just does what it says, it asks inputs until a blank is input:

```
$> p inputs_until_empty("> ").to_a

[19:29:12] > : 1
[19:29:21] > : 2
[19:29:21] > : 3
[19:29:21] > : 
["1", "2", "3"]
```

And you can use it in `work_performed`

```
def work_performed
  Enumerator.new do |e|
    (0..Float::INFINITY).each do |count|
      input = prompt("Enter work notes[#{count}]")
      break if input.empty?
      e.yield "\n#{input}\n"
      e.yield inputs_until_empty('Enter work notes[*]')
                .map{|x| "  - #{x}\n"}.join + "\n"
    end
  end
end
```

The only difference is that you will need to join the result by newline to get a string out of this function.

But the repetition remains and the code is more "weird" so maybe your simpler / more direct approach is still better.

Comment: This breaks after one blank line is given for me

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome isn't it intended behaviour?

Comment: I mean it completely breaks the loop after one line is given not two, it doesn't move to the next level of notes

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome maybe I should just delete this answer, it is overcomplicated (I have no idea on how to fix it)

Comment: Lol, don't get me wrong, I like the answer and it's a great one. Just doesn't end when I want it to.

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome Ok, I will see how I can make this code behave the same as the one in the question.

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome I think the functionality of my code is the same as the code given in the question, where is the difference?